# Hibernate Session Level Cache : Login issue

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, second-level-cache

This is the problem asked to me by one of my seniors.

1)  We have two different nodes of a J2EE Application Server : Node 1 and Node 2. (As shown in the image below.)

2) Also hibernate second level cache is being enabled.

3) Problem is as follows: A User hits the login page URL and assume that this request goes to Node 1 and User Logs in and then User Logs Out.

4) Again User request for Login page and this time, request goes to Node 2. Now User logs in and changes his password and Logs out.

> > Now the Question is when user tries to login with his new password
> >     and request goes to Node 1. Will he be able to login into the system ?
>
> If he is not able to do it, what could be done to make user login with
>   his new password on Node 1.

```
Note: We have a LoginUser table where the Username and passwords are stored.
```

[image]

**My Answer :**

As per my opinion, it could be the case that when User tries to login using Node 1 and then logs out.

Hibernate fires this query:

select * from Login where username = "John";

And this entry is cached in the second level cache of node 1.

Now when he logs in into the system using  Node 2 and changes his password. And again tries to login to Node 1, he is not able to log in using his new password, because this time Second level cache of node 1 is containing the old password, So he can login using his old password.

This is the reason why he is not able to login to node 1 with new password.

Now the solution of this problem could be the replication of second level cache.

> Kindly share your inputs on the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your problem is a distributed second level cache as described in the Hibernate documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#cacheproviders). Infinispan is the best supported platform. You can read about setting this up on the Jboss [wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider).

This will take care of invalidating the 2LC across the cluster when cached data changes on either node. The node the users requests hits will then know that the cache is stale and will go to the database to load the required fresh data.

Comment: So you mean to say that its a valid problem ?

Comment: It's a very valid problem. Cache invalidation is always a tricky issue. Luckily for us we have tools like Infinispan and JGroups to abstract the complexity behind some simple configuration.

Comment: As per my knowledge, every node in the server has its own sessionfactory, so two nodes have two completely different Second Level caches. Isn't this the case?

Comment: Each node does have its own 2LC however they communicate via JGroups. When a change happens on one node and the cache is invalidated all other nodes are notified and they invalidate their caches too. It's all explained in the linked docs.

Comment: Alex, good answer :). To build upon on it: Not sure the app server you're using, but JBoss EAP 6.1 comes with Infinispan as default second level cache provider, which can be clustered if you start two containers with the standalone-ha.xml configuration. For any other container, you can find an example on how to cluster Infinispan second level cache here: https://github.com/galderz/secondlc/blob/master/src/test/java/secondlc/Cluster2lcTest.java